# Playwright not all data printed

Tags: python, string, playwright

I made a script to parse a website

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright





with sync_playwright() as p:
    
    browser = p.webkit.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=50)

   
    page = browser.new_page()

    
    page_path = "https://xtreme-gacha.com/bbs/"

   
    page.goto(page_path, timeout=0 )
    
    page.select_option('#accountsTable_length > label > select', value='50')

    
    page_content = page.content()

    
    htm = page.inner_html('#accountsTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > div:nth-child(4)')
    print(htm)
```

I printed what I wanted to print, but what was printed is just 2% of the total data, and the string is cut in the middle.

As the output is large I couldn't write it here.

Comment: Seems like python has limitation on default variables, maybe try to increase the memory of the variable , just wild guess

Comment: Yeah, I thought so but I tried another website and it cuts the string too when I compared the word count I found that there was a different of 50+ words between the strings.